# How do I edit line and fill setting when using Add Feature?

Tags: qgis-2

Newbie here. I see that the creation of new shape layers must be possible, but I cannot work out how to do so without QGIS only using the default ugly green fill polygon setting. Is there a way to create non-ugly polygons in QGIS please, ideally with no fill so I can actually see what is underneath?

I have searched but all the answers appear to be in Python code, rather than "you do it like this" answers.

[image: Ugly polygon]

Comment: This post might also be useful where you can set a default style like in the answer below: [How does one style the border to match the fill in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191022/how-does-one-style-the-border-to-match-the-fill-in-qgis)

Comment: As a newbie, I advice you to look into QGIS Users manual. This kind of basic questions are all answered there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Alexandre, but these questions are typically not answered in the Manual in such a manner as to be generally interpretable by newbies. It simply isn't possible for experts to write for newbies and the advice received here is often much more clear than in the manual. Please be assured that your patience and time is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- select the layer;
- right mouse button;
- property;
- see attached image.

[image: screenshot]