# Graduated symbology shows borders between matching categories

Tags: qgis, symbology, outline

I'm using graduated symbology on a vector layer in QGIS and i do not want lines between polygons of the same color. I tried making the border outline transparent, and also setting the border outline to match the fill color and set the border width to 1. I can still see a thin grey border regardless of the settings.

I should add, i'm trying to do this in python. This worked in QGIS but not python: [Styling border to match fill in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191022/styling-border-to-match-fill-in-qgis)

```
for actmin, actmax, myLabel, myColor in ranges:
    mySymbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(maplayer.geometryType())
    mySymbol.setColor(myColor)
    mySymbol.setAlpha(myOpacity) mySymbol.symbolLayer(0).setDataDefinedProperty('color_border','color_rgba'+str(rgbacolors[i]))  
        myRange = QgsRendererRangeV2(actmin, actmax, mySymbol, myLabel)
        myRangeList.append(myRange)
        i+=1

myRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2('', myRangeList)
myRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.Quantile)
myRenderer.setClassAttribute(mappingcol)
maplayer.setRendererV2(myRenderer)
```

[image: The border line]

[image: No pen outline style, width of 0, outline color matches fill color]

[image: Pen outline width of 0 with fill matching outline color]

Comment: Set the border color using the expression @symbol_color.

Comment: Oops, I re-read your question and realized you already tried setting the border outline same as fill. The issue may be that there are small gaps between your polygons. You could correct the geometry using snapping, or simply make the outlines wider.

Comment: This worked for the actual QGS file path, but when trying to do it in python, the borders reappear... am i missing something?