# Overlapping polygons produce rendering artifacts a low zoom

Tags: qgis, mapnik, rendering

I have duplicated this problem in both QGIS and mapnik. For this question, I will show the problem using QGIS.

I have imported heightmap images along a coastal area.

[image]

I then added an overlay layer with [split water polygons](https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/water-polygons.html) from OSM. This renders perfectly fine at higher zoom levels:

[image]

Once I start to zoom out, lines appear between the water polygons. These lines make it into the final rendered image.

[image]

What can I do to remove these lines?

Comment: Have you tried the solution in this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191022/styling-border-to-match-fill-in-qgis?

Comment: @ahmadhanb I had the boarder set to "no pen". I changed it to "solid line" and set the color to match the fill. This seemed to solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Then this question will be marked as a duplicate to the suggested one.